# automate selection and press enter for simple bash script

Tags: bash, auto-populating

I would like to sush2 into a remote device then run commands, but the system requires the user to enter the letter "t" then press enter.

I would like to be able to paste the device hostname after script then have the script enter the letter "t" and "press" enter then execute commands I enter into the bash script after I am logged into the device.

How can I automate this process?

I tried echo "t"

I was hoping the echo command would work

This is how I execute the bash script:

[mydevserver ~]$ ./sush2v2.sh [hostname]

my script:

#!/bin/bash

host="$1"

sush2 "$host"

Comment: Look into using `expect` instead of `bash`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.